# MySQL group by time buckets

Tags: mysql

I have a activity log with the following schema:

```
visitor_id, metadata, timestamp
```

The first field is the visitors id, the second some metadata for a given activity and the last a unix timestamp from when the activity occurred.

Now, i want to identify individual sessions from this log. That is; i want to group all rows for each visitor where the timestamp is no longer then x seconds apart (eg. 20*60 for 20 minutes) from either the previous or following row by the same visitor.

How can that be done?

Comment: It will probably be better to do it in application logic.

Comment: I think it will be better to do it in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like custom groups like this:

```
SELECT
    t.visitor_id,
    MIN(t.timestamp),
    MAX(t.timestamp)
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(@lt < l.`timestamp` - 60*20 OR l.visitor_id != @lv, @g := @g + 1, @g) as g,
        @lv := l.visitor_id,
        @lt := l.`timestamp`,
        l.*
    FROM your_log l
    JOIN (SELECT @g := 1, @lt = 0, @lv = NULL) as init
    ORDER BY l.visitor_id, l.`timestamp`
) as t
GROUP BY t.visitor_id, g
```

Comment: you would need to order by visitor AND timestamp, otherwise, your timestamp crossing same visitor would falsely continue based on individual person basis... At least that is what I am interpreting from the original post.

Comment: @DRapp yep, thanks for that. It also needs to start a new group when the user changes...